# using a loop to invoke multiple methods

Tags: java

I am newish to Java and trying to building a small rocket program.

I have 3 distinct methods that change the size and colour of the rockets exhaust jet on the graphical display when invoked which work great individually.

```
public void pulse1()
{
    jet.setDiameter(6);
    jet.setColour(OUColour.RED);
    jet.setXPos(58);
}

public void pulse2()
{
    jet.setDiameter(12);
    jet.setColour(OUColour.ORANGE);
    jet.setXPos(55);
}

public void pulse3()
{    
    jet.setDiameter(24);
    jet.setColour(OUColour.RED);
    jet.setXPos(48);
}
```

However, what I am trying to do is code another method `ignition()` that uses some sort of loop to invoke each of the three pulse methods in that chronological order a maximum of 5 times with a 500 millisecond delay between each call. (the idea being to simulate on the graphical display the firing up of the rockets engines)

Thus far I have tried the following without success.

```
public void ignition()
{
    pulse1();
    delay(500); // uses the inbuilt delay method
    pulse2();
    delay(500);
    pulse3();
}
```

Comment: There's no "inbuilt delay method" in Java. Are you using some kind of framework? And what isn't working about the code you've tried?

Comment: Be careful if you're sleeping on the graphics thread. It's possibly not redrawing for the entire duration of the `ignition` method.

Comment: Yes its a framework that has been provided by the educational establishment, (It has a nested delay method) that I can use but not see the code for. As I said in the post, I am trying to develop a method that invokes all of pulse methods with a 500 millisecond delay

Comment: as you are not definite on how many times each of the 3 methods should be invoked. You could use a random no. generator to create a number between 1 and 5. use that as your triggering condition .

Comment: Since all three methods are basically doing the same thing, you could just make it one method with three parameters, or, following the idea by @IndraneelBende, just use random colors and diameters, possibly making the "flame" animation much more realistic. Then just let that loop a few times with a delay in between iterations.

Comment: @SyntaxKiller Speak to your teacher about it. We can't help you with a proprietary framework we have no experience or knowledge of. As I said above, I suspect you'll need to move all of this to another thread.

Comment: Sorry, the **real** feedback at this point is: please turn to [help] to learn how/what to ask here. This is not programming school where you drop some code and vague requirements, to then *work* with tutors in order to get the whole thing finished. This community is about clear, crips questions that stand for themselves and that can be answered in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a loop will execute the contents of a **code block**. A code block is anything between two curly braces.

```
{
    statement1;
    statement2;
} // statement2 and statement2 are both inside the code block
```

So, when you declare a loop (perhaps with `for` or `while`), the loop will act on the very next code block. You can simply call the delay function once each time within the loop block, and it will wait once per loop.

A way to achieve what you are talking about using a `for` loop might be like so

```
public void ignition() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         pulse1();
         delay(500); // uses the inbuilt delay method
         pulse2();
         delay(500);
         pulse3();
         delay(500);

    }
```

EDIT: Misinterpreted what OP wanted to loop through

Comment: appreciate the answer, will try and revert back

Answer (score 0):

As you are not definite on how many number of times you should traverse in a loop but have a maximum limit of 5, use a random no. generator.

```
       int  i = rand.nextInt(5) + 1; //1 is minimum and 5 is maximum
       int a=0;
       while(a<i){

        pulse1();
        delay(500); // uses the inbuilt delay method
        pulse2();
        delay(500);
        pulse3();
        a++;

     }
```

You could also use Thread.sleep(500) if your delay method is giving you issues.

Comment: appreciate the answer, will try and revert back